# Reading packets from WinSock hook

Tags: c++, hex, winsock

I'm writing a packet viewer for an online game, and everything was going well until now.

I'm facing the following problem: my code is ignoring some characters on the packet.

Here's an example of a packet when I'm using a software like Wireshark or WPE:

[image: packet]

That packet has 36 bytes, where the second hexadecimal number is the packet length minus the two first bytes (just explaining ^^).

Like I said, the above packet is what I get using WPE/Wireshark. Now let's see what I'm getting using my code:

`03 22 0a c3 aa c3 aa c3 aa c3 aa c3 aa 10 9a 46 c1 c0 48 6f ae c8 52 f1 c2 86 c2 ea 2c 7d`

Do you see the difference? The packet (in part) is the same with 36 bytes of length, but the last 6 bytes are omitted, i.e, `00 04 FF FF FF FF`. Why is this happening?

Here is my code that captures packets:

```
int WINAPI SendHook(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    if (buf[0] == 0x03) {
        ofstream testfile;
        string hex = Hex::ToUtf8Hex(string(buf));    //packet hex data

        testfile.open("C:/test.txt", std::ios_base::app || std::ios_base::ate);
        testfile << hex;
        tesfile.close();
    }
    return pSend(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```

Comment: stop on 0 byte. you can not use data as 0 terminating string. `string(buf)` - this is error. buf not 0-terminating string. must be `string(buf, len)`

Comment: Also, in the call to `testfile.open()`, the use of `||` (logical OR) is wrong, you need to use `|` (bitwise OR) instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, now i have a doubt, how can i print a byte like `04`, using my code? i'm seeing only `4`, the code is omitting the first `0`

Comment: @RbMM can you help me?

Comment: @RenanMoura - in what ?

Comment: @RbMM on my doubt above

Comment: you at all not need `Hex::ToUtf8Hex`. need simply code like this `int i = 0; do { printf("%02x ", *buf++);  if (!(++i & 15)) printf("\n")} while(--len);`

Comment: @RbMM how can i storage the output of your code?

Comment: in what problem ? print to string for example and than save this string

Comment: @RbMM oh, okay ^^ thank you so much